# Severe glitch when navigating to a screen with google_mobile_ads

Tags: android, flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

Upgrading to `Flutter 2.8.1` causes flickering when navigating between screens in apps that contain ads. In particular, the flickering happens when navigating to a new screen from another screen that has a banner ad. When commenting out the banner the flickering goes away.

The problem is not producible using Flutter 2.5.3.

The issue was originally raised in [googleads-mobile-flutter](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/467) but after investigating the issue further it is now believed to be a problem with the Flutter SDK.

To produce the problem, run the attached application code using `google_mobile_ads: 1.0.1` and Flutter 2.8.0.

Video sample, code sample and flutter doctor -v output produced by @maheshmnj

> Code sample:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen());
  }
}



class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('Item $index'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return const ProducDetailPage();
                }));
              },
            );
          })),
          const CustomBannerAd()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ProducDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProducDetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Produc Detail'),
        ),
        body: Column(children: const [
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            child: Placeholder(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            child: Placeholder(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
          CustomBannerAd()
        ]));
  }
}

class CustomBannerAd extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomBannerAd({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomBannerAdState createState() => _CustomBannerAdState();
}

class _CustomBannerAdState extends State<CustomBannerAd> {
  BannerAd? _anchoredAdaptiveAd;
  var _isLoaded = false;
  late Orientation _currentOrientation;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    _currentOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    _loadAd();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

    _anchoredAdaptiveAd?.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _loadAd() async {
    await _anchoredAdaptiveAd?.dispose();

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        _anchoredAdaptiveAd = null;
        _isLoaded = false;
      });
    }

    final AnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize? size =
        await AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.truncate());

    if (size == null) {
      debugPrint('Unable to get height of anchored banner.');
      return;
    }

    _anchoredAdaptiveAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'
          : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716',
      size: size,
      request: const AdRequest(
        nonPersonalizedAds: false,
      ),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          debugPrint("Ad loaded");
          if (mounted) {
            setState(() {
              _anchoredAdaptiveAd = ad as BannerAd;
              _isLoaded = true;
            });
          }
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          debugPrint('$BannerAd failedToLoad: $error');
          ad.dispose();
        },
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => debugPrint('$BannerAd onAdOpened.'),
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => debugPrint('$BannerAd onAdClosed.'),
      ),
    );

    return _anchoredAdaptiveAd?.load();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
      if (_currentOrientation == orientation &&
          _anchoredAdaptiveAd != null &&
          _isLoaded) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          width: _anchoredAdaptiveAd!.size.width.toDouble(),
          height: _anchoredAdaptiveAd?.size.height.toDouble(),
          child: AdWidget(ad: _anchoredAdaptiveAd!),
        );
      }

      // Reload the ad if the orientation changes.
      if (_currentOrientation != orientation) {
        _currentOrientation = orientation;
        _loadAd();
      }
      return const SizedBox.shrink();
    });
  }
}
```

> is there any solution?

[Screenshots and videos](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95343)

Comment: that could be due to multiple rebuilds of the screen

Answer (score 4):

change your **google_mobile_ads** plugin with this :

```
google_mobile_ads:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/SuaMusica/googleads-mobile-flutter.git
      path: packages/google_mobile_ads
      ref: feature/suamusica
```

if there is a yellow underscore in git text, just add the following code to pubspec.yaml

```
publish_to: 'none'
```

Comment: perfect! i can confirm it works flawlessly. no flickers!

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue. And it's only when you used fluter sdk 2.8 to 2.10. It's also raised on flutter github repo. (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95343).

The solution is to upgrade flutter sdk to 3.0.2 and update google_mobile_ads 1.3.0.